# React.js and Jasmine Spies

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, reactjs-testutils

Using basic test-utils and jasmine for unit testing.

How do you spy on a function inside a react component?

test.js:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    // Do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="test-class" onClick={this.handleClick}>Test</div>
    );
  }
}

const React = require('react-with-addons');
const RequireJsTest = require('requirejs-test');
const Utils = React.addons.TestUtils;
const Test = require('./test');

describe('test', () => {
  it('should test', function() {
    const test = Utils.renderIntoDocument(<Test/>);
    const el = Utils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(test, 'test-class');
    spyOn(test, 'handleClick');
    Utils.Simulate.click(el);

    expect(test.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Expected spy handleClick to have been called. (1)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I haven't tested react apps yet, but try the [method](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme#full-dom-rendering) (the last test in describe block), which I've just found in [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) readme doc.

I think you should spy on component class prototype method before rendering component:

```
spyOn(Test.prototype, 'handleClick');
// and then
expect(Test.prototype.handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
```